# Multiple LED's, one controller, diagram included

Tags: led, led-strip, rgb

I want to make sure that my logic is correct and this would work.

I'm trying to control 5, 16.4' LED strips of 5050 RGB SMD's at 60 LEDs/m or 300/strip.  I want all of them to be ran off the single controller.

I believe my 360w power supply would be enough (extreme overkill?).  I came up with an idea to use terminal blocks to run the LEDs as opposed to direct connecting them to the signal amplifier.  The purpose of this was so that I can use ring terminals to connect two of the LED strips to the terminal block, then have one set of wires running to the amplifier.

I plan to run the output from the controller to another terminal block and connect the `signal/power amplifiers` to that.  The RF controller has the power to run a single 5050 strip on its own so I figure I would directly connect it to this terminal block.

In case you can't see it in the photo:

LED Specs are 60w max per strip, 8.64 watts/meter operating wattage or 43.2w/single strip.  My diagram shows this wrong.

RGB Controller is a 12-24v/12A output, 12v input

Power supply is a Regulated Switching, 3-channel, 360w power supply, 12v/30A output.

**`Extra large diagram link:`**  https://www.dropbox.com/s/q7kdv4amaaidg03/LED-Diagram.png?dl=0

[image]

Answer (score 1):

<strike>At full white you are looking at 30 amps 12V. I doubt your supply handles 30 amps on the 12v rail alone. And that would fry your controller.</strike>

you need a supply that can provide 400W or so or more on the 12v alone.

Look into the rgb power amplifiers or power injectors. These take the signal from the controller and provide separate control for another strip.

Your text does not mention the power amplifiers. But the diagram does. As long as your supply can safely do 360 watts, you should be good. If anything, you might want to power the strips from the middle instead of the end, to ensure better uniformity in color. But you have it handled.

Comment: Power amplifiers are on either side of the RF controller on the diagram, I think.  http://www.ecolocityled.com/product/rgb_led_signal_repeater/rgb_signal_amplifiers

Comment: Color me embarrassed

Comment: I was starting to wonder if I had missed something :)

Comment: I called them signal amplifiers, not power amps.  Updated it just in case there is difference in terminology.

Comment: +1 for powering strips from the middle. It probably won't be a problem with 300 LEDs but you may notice the colour temperature change along the length of the strip.

Comment: Just to update the project is complete. I was able to power 5, 16' strips using the amps and single supply with no issues of color temperature. I did cut them down an only used 32' total so that helped.